# Disable sleep mode in mobile phone when camera is in 'on' in a mobile app

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have done a mobile app(live video streaming from mobile phone). Normally in mobile phones when the camera is in on the mobile backlight does not go to sleep mode but in my app i have written code to attach a camera and when i start to stream from the app then after some time the mobile goes to sleepmode. **I need to make an application that should be able to make the phone light off when video is streaming.** How can i achieve this ?
Here is my code,

```
            camera = null;
            netStreamPublisher.attachCamera(null);

            if (cameraPosition == "auto") {
                camera = Camera.getCamera();
                trace("Entered auto");
            } else {
                if (Camera.names.length == 1) {
                    camera = Camera.getCamera();
                    trace("Entered camera");
                } else {
                    var tmpCamera:Camera = null;
                    trace("Entered");
                    for (var i:uint = 0; i < Camera.names.length; i++) {
                        tmpCamera = Camera.getCamera(Camera.names[i]);
                        if (tmpCamera.position == cameraPosition) {
                            camera = tmpCamera;
                            trace("Entered");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (camera) {
                camera.setMode (640, 480, 15, true);
                camera.setQuality (15000, 0); // 30000, 0 (adobe settings)
                netStreamPublisher.attachCamera (camera);
                return camera;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import these classes...

```
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import flash.desktop.SystemIdleMode;
```

Then set this to prevent the device from sleeping.

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
```

After you have used the camera you can if you wish, revert back to a sleepable mode with...

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.NORMAL
```